# Metawhere abstract conditions from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, meta-where

I'm using the Metawhere rails gem to query my dbase. I have a query that works:

```
t=Model.where({:attr1 => 450} | {:attr2 => 450}, :lang => 2)
```

now I trying to abstract the conditions from the query like this:

```
conditions=Hash[{:attr1 => 450} | {:attr2 => 450}, :lang => 2]
t=Model.where(conditions)
```

but the first line gives me: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ']

I tried a lot of things like making the conditions a string and eval(conditions) in the query. but that gives me SyntaxError: (eval):1:in `irb_binding': compile error
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end

I'm stuck. If you can help me that would be appreciated.

Rutger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
conditions=Hash[{:attr1 => 450} | {:attr2 => 450}, :lang => 2}]
```

with

```
conditions=Hash[{:attr1 => 450} | {:attr2 => 450}, :lang => 2]
```

Comment: Alex,Argh, sorry that was i typoe in my code above (I adjusted it). In the real code that bracket was not there so thanks for the tip but not a solution to my problem

Comment: So, you still have error `unexpected tASSOC, expecting ']` even without that bracket?

Comment: By the way, try this condition `conditions = [{:attr1 => 450} | {:attr2 => 450}, :lang => 2]`